# How to see logs of an Airflow operator when testing

Tags: python, logging, airflow

I created a custom BashOperator like this

```
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

class CustomOperator(BashOperator):
    """ 
    Custom bash operator that just write whatever it is given as stmt 
    The actual operator is more complex
    """

    def __init__(self, stmt, **kwargs):
        cmd = 'echo %s > /path/to/some/file.txt' % stmt
        super().__init__(bash_command=cmd, **kwargs)
```

Then I created a test for this operator

```
from datetime import datetime
from unittest import TestCase

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import TaskInstance

class CustomOperatorTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_execute(self):
        dag = DAG(dag_id='test', start_date=datetime.now())
        stmt = "hello world"
        task = CustomOperator(stmt=stmt, task_id='custom', dag=dag)
        ti = TaskInstance(task=task, execution_date=datetime.now())
        task.execute(ti.get_template_context())
        with open('/path/to/some/file.txt', 'r') as f:
            self.assert(f.read(), stmt)
```

So far so good, but let's assume I have an error somewhere in my `CustomOperator`. For example I mispelled `echo` to `eko`. The only message I get in the console is:

```
ERROR: test_execute (tests.operators.test_custom_operator.CustomOperatorTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/tests/operators/test_shp2pgsql_operator.py", line 26, in test_execute
    result = task.execute(ti.get_template_context())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 135, in execute
    raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed
```

I have no way of debugging. The only solution I have so far is to trigger a dag containing this task in the web UI and go to the logs tab.

How can I see the logs of the operator in the console when testing ?

Answer (score 4):

It turned out I just needed to add an handler to the logger `airflow.task.operators` at the beginning of my test file

```
import logging 
import sys

log = logging.getLogger("airflow.task.operators")
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.addHandler(handler)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use airflow test command + pysnooper. It will give you instance and detail debug info.

1. Simple mode(Just use airflow test command)

   airflow test test custom 20190704
   The above command will run the task without dependence. and print all info to you console.
2. Complex mode( airflow test + pysnooper)
   You need install pysonnper in advance by pip install pysnooper. and import pysnooper in py file, and put @pysnooper.snoop() decorator just below the function you want to call. 
   And then run

   airflow test test custom 20190704

You can detail logs, every line execution and variable create/change info will be print to your console.

Good luck
If you feel the answer helpful, pls vote it up

Comment: That's interesting, but ideally I would like a solution that rely solely on unittest. It seems to me it's just a matter of tuning the logging so that it print to stout